Older anime with androids, a girl, a giant refuse pile of metal parts, a elysium like giant island chained to the ground. Possibly 90s
Any clues? Think it was a short(ish) story, or OVA, not part of a larger series. Don't think it was a big movie like a typical Ghibli movie, but was like 2 parts if I remember correctly?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Angel_Alita? Not to be confused with the film of the same name. - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Irw6eVvkxPo

Thanks much very. A comment at a related youtube video of the movie claimed it was a masterpiece, which seems widely agreed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0mDhVJZB3S8

@AstarWstar Don't forget to mark the below answer as accepted if it helped you

This is Battle Angel: Alita (1993).
Androids, a big pile of scrap and a floating city chained to the ground are all key features.




The youtube link you posted is marked blocked for me as being "age restricted".  I don't have a youtube account, so I am definitely not logged into youtube.  But weirdly if go to the link I can click through a warning and actually see the video.
